# Can not call value of non function type

Tags: swift

I am getting error can not call value of non function type. Whats wrong in this ?

```
extension FileModel {
    var isPlayableMedia: Bool {
        get {
            return isPlayableMedia(mediaType: mediaType)
        }
    }

    func isPlayableMedia(_ mediaType: MediaType) -> Bool {
        return mediaType == MediaType.image ||  mediaType == MediaType.video
    }
}
```

Comment: In Swift variables and functions can't have same name, changing one of them will work (it was possible in Objective-C but not anymore in Swift): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29016524/swift-variable-with-same-as-a-method-name

Answer (score 1):

Either remove the label parameter when the method is called

```
var isPlayableMedia: Bool {
    return isPlayableMedia(mediaType) // assuming `mediaType` is declared somewhere else.
}
```

Or specify the label parameter in the declaration (remove the underscore)

```
func isPlayableMedia(mediaType: MediaType) -> Bool {
    return mediaType == MediaType.image ||  mediaType == MediaType.video
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing much just check your function signature and use it in right way.

replace your var with the following code :

```
var isPlayableMedia: Bool {
    get {
        return isPlayableMedia(mediaType)
    }
}
```

OR 
just remove the argument label from you method calling